# Visual studio 2010 Express- how does one copy project properties?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I found it strangely that this question was rarely asked so I decided to bring it up:

How does one copy project properties from an existing one?
I tried the project manager way but it doesn't work. I saved the old properties somewhere and "add existing property sheet" but nothing happened. The presumably added SDL files does not show up in the configurations. And somehow after hours of struggling my old project lost its property so I decided to give up and seek help here.

But honestly I don't understand why this intuitive function was made so difficult. I meant the configuration is simply a text file so why it is so difficult to copy that file?

Answer (score 0):

OK so I figure out...the "add new..." actually really only gives me a blank property sheet and I have to modify it again and save and then I can share it around the projects.

Oh my, a bit speechless.